# Prevent Restkit from Deleting Orphaned Objects if Server error 401

Tags: core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20, http-status-code-401

In my app I use Restkit to map the JSON response into core data. I use - [addFetchRequestBlock](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html) - so that restkit will cleanup  orphaned objects.

// Cleanup of orphaned objects

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {

    // Value returned from the relativePath
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"/filesystem/v1/folder/:folderId"];

    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];

    NSString *folderID;

    if (match)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ADStorageEntity"];

        // Get the folder ID
        folderID = [argsDict objectForKey:@"folderId"];

        // Setup the fetchRequest
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent = %@", @([folderID integerValue])]; // NOTE: Coerced from string to number

        return fetchRequest;
    }

    return nil;

}];
```

All works well, but if I have an auth error 401

> File List Request Failed with Error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Loaded an unprocessable error response (401)

all the managed objects in the "/:folderId" are treated as orphaned objects and gets deleted.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour and not perform an orphaned objects cleanup?

EDIT -

Seems I was mapping the error

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error.code" toKeyPath:@"code"]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error.message" toKeyPath:@"message"]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error.description" toKeyPath:@"description"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"error" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[errorDescriptor]];
```

after deleting the error mapping, the Fetch Request Block was not called

Comment: Fetch request blocks are only used on successful mappings, if the 401 raises an error then nothing should be deleted. How is 401 used / treated by your response descriptors / configuration?

Comment: @Wain Thank you for the comment, it led me to find the problem (See the "edit")..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch request blocks are only used on successful mappings, if the 401 raises an error then nothing should be deleted - if you don't have a mapping for it.

`RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)` covers all of the codes in the 4xx range. You don't need to use that. If you want to ignore the `401` response from the mapping then you can create an index set containing only `400` (or `400`, `402`, etc as required).